# How do I set multiprocessing_context to "spawn" in my code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, spawn

I'm tryint to run a [tutorial](https://github.com/gretelai/gretel-synthetics/blob/master/examples/timeseries_dgan.ipynb)
on my local Windows, but always get an error for this line of code:

```
model.train_numpy(features,feature_types=[OutputType.CONTINUOUS] * features.shape[2])
```

And this is the error I get: ValueError: multiprocessing_context option should specify a valid start method in ['spawn'], but got multiprocessing_context='fork'

Right after the imports I added:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

But I still got the same error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming from code internal to gretel_synthetics, that [overrides](https://github.com/gretelai/gretel-synthetics/blob/90b149036311d7e85357e2f721170812943c5e8d/src/gretel_synthetics/timeseries_dgan/dgan.py#L737) your multiprocessing context:

```
loader = DataLoader(
    dataset,
    self.config.batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=drop_last,
    num_workers=2,
    prefetch_factor=4,
    persistent_workers=True,
    pin_memory=True,
    multiprocessing_context="fork",
)
```

This is incompatible with Windows. You could try submitting a [bug report](https://github.com/gretelai/gretel-synthetics/issues) and hoping they fix this.